# I am trying to connect my eclipse with oracle 11_g but it is asking for ojdbc14.jar

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle11g

I want to connect 11_g with my eclipse but it is continously asking for ojdbc14.jar

Comment: share your error message

Comment: Yes your eclipse is correct. You need jar file to connect to Oracle. Have you added it?

Comment: @PradeepSimha I added the jar file that comes with 11_g that is ojdbc6.jar but it is only asking for ojdbc14.jar

Comment: Then post relevant code and error message you are getting.

Comment: What is your jdk version that you set?

Comment: @newuserua_ext jdk 1.7

Answer (score 2):

ojdbc14.jar and ojdbc12.jar are required files to connect database with java program which is present on Eclipse.
So you can download ojdbc14.jar from internet or it will present inside your oracle11g folder and add into eclipse.
steps to connect Oracle instance from Eclipse:
1)In Eclipse IDE and Select Database Perspective-Windows->Open Perspective->Other->Database Development).
2)Create Connection Profile, Chose Oracle
3)Choose JDBC Driver and specify its location
4)Specify connection detail e.g. localhost, port(8080), username and password ORACLE database
5)check Test Connection

Comment: Thanks @Sauabhagya let me try it.